# DRF serializer method field returns previous field data after updating in update() method

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a serializer in which I need to update the related model and return the updated value using the serializer method field.

```
class MultiUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    shared_user = UserBaseSerializer(required=False)
    enforce_mfa = serializers.SerializerMethodField(default=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MultiUser
        depth = 1
        fields = [
            'shared_user',
            'enforce_mfa',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        
        if self.context['request'].data.get('enforce_mfa'):
            # Say enforce_mfa = True
            enforce_mfa = json.loads(str(self.context['request'].data.get('enforce_mfa')).lower())

            preference, create = Preference.objects.get_or_create(user=instance.shared_user)
            preference.enforce_mfa = enforce_mfa
            preference.save()

            print('This prints True: {}'.format(preference.enforce_mfa))

        instance_ = super().update(instance, validated_data)

        return instance_

    def get_enforce_mfa(self, obj):

        try:
            a = obj.shared_user.preference.enforce_mfa
            print('This remains False {}'.format(a))
            return a
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return False  # Return False in case of preference does not exist.
```

After updating the `Preference` model inside the `update()` method, the value is updated successfully but the value returned from `get_enforce_mfa()` method is still the previous value.

Say if the previous value of `enforce_mfa` is *False*, and the value is updated to *True*, it still returns *False* from the `get_enforce_mfa()` method.

Comment: Have you tried using the `perform_update` instead of `update` ? You can add behavior that occurs before or after saving an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `refresh_from_db()`:

```py
    def get_enforce_mfa(self, obj):

        try:
            preference = obj.shared_user.preference
            preference.refresh_from_db()
            return preference.enforce_mfa
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return False  # Return False in case of preference does not exist.
```

Here's the documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136315/12330426).

The reason that it's not updating the field's value is because the 'SerializerMethodField' is read_only in DRF.